# I don't suppose it would be possible to programatically turn on data roaming

Tags: ios

I hesitate to ask, as I'm sure the answer will be that its not possible, but I need to confirm if its possible to programatically turn on data roaming (the user may have given permission to permit this feature beforehand).

Comment: I doubt it.  Last thing I would want is for that to happen to me.  Even if I approved it a few months back and then go on vacation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No its not possible... if you do this somehow .. apple will reject your app to publish in app store